# What is the right way of consulting vimeo CDN for custom player?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

using the api against /videos/ID I get a bunch of links, select the corret format and them i'm good to play on my own website.

But it's slow, i'm not on USA and it's slow for my customers.

(I'm a vimeo PRO subscriber)

Recently, checking a similar website, I've noticed that their urls are generates like

https://13-lvl3-pdl.vimeocdn.com/01/1924/4/....

And mine are generated like

https://fpdl.vimeocdn.com/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/4067/6/...

The first one, that i could not discover how to get on my own videos, is really faster and lower latency.

Any light on this would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These urls are dynamically generated on the server. There is no programatic way that you can change which CDN url you receive.

Please reach out to vimeo.com so they can dig more into why it performs so slowly for you.

Answer (score 1):

After upload and process video by vimeo it generates HD,SD and HLS links.
Sometime speed depends on many factors like hosting environment, player used for stream videos,Internet bandwidth etc etc.

**So first check following things:**

1) Are you using third party player for stream your videos?

2) Are you using HLS video link for stream video?

3) What is your hosting environment in terms of server response time?

**Some Suggestion to achieve better video streamming:**

1) Get best Hosting plan which has better server response time.

2) Use vimeo default player for stream videos.

3) If you are using third party player than use HLS vimeo generated link with Third party HLS player.

**Some HLS player links**

http://www.hlsplayer.net/

http://osmfhls.kutu.ru/

http://www.flashls.org/latest/examples/chromeless/

http://dailymotion.github.io/hls.js/demo/

http://www.dash-player.com/demo/hls/

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely select which CDN you can load your videos from. Vimeo uses three CDNs and you can set a cookie that will indicate to the player which cdn to use. Check out this link: https://player.vimeo.com/flags 
Here you can select the cdn and it sets the cookie I was mentioning. You can set this cookie for your users on your website and the video will be fetched from that cdn.